# Eloquent: Inserts 0.00 instead of the actual float value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I've a field called `hoursWorked` in my table:

```
$table->float('HoursWorked',2,2);
```

In MySQL:

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| HoursWorked       | double(2,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

In my model I've specified that this field is double(2,2) in $casts array:

```
protected $casts = [
        'hoursWorked' => "double(2,2)"
];
```

And the field is marked as fillable
I'm passing JSON object with the following format:

```
...Some data
 "hoursWorked":"6.55",
...Some data
```

Which I'm later turning into array and I'm passing it to `::create` method of the model. However after insertion (which is happening without any errors) the data stored in the database is 0.00. I tried removing the `" "` around the number but it didn't work. Any ideas how I may proceed.

Edit:
Here is the code where the query runs:

```
$m = \App\Models\Timesheet::class;
foreach($request->json()->get('timesheets') as $timesheet){
    $validator = Validator::make($timesheet, $m::$rules, ['required' => trans("errors.required_field")]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        break;
    }else{
         $m::create($timesheet);
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the query that runs? can we see it?

Comment: I added this information in the answer

Comment: i still dont see a query?

Comment: What do you mean by query. I haven't written any SQL for this. Eloquent is responsible for the query

Comment: I fixed the issue. The problem was a type in the fillable array.

Comment: Just a note: be careful storing float values in the database, better to deal with integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default. While using create method, eloquent does not assign a value to the protected attributes.

You may use `$guarded` property

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

or `$fillable` property of `\App\Models\Timesheet` Model

```
protected $fillable = ['HoursWorked'];
```